# i can not manage to record/access derivatives

Tags: openmdao

The sample case for recording/accessing derivatives in [this link](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/features/recording/reading_data.html?highlight=record%20derivatives) works fine for me, if i simply copy paste the code.
I am trying to figure out why the similar method does not work for my own problem . I set the recording options identical. I tried to list some differences but not sure if they can be the cause of this:

- I have an extra maxiter option so optimizer ''fails'' after 3 iterations.
- I can access all other recorded variables (objectives, constraints,list_output)
- I can not access to list_inputs though this is also the case for the sample code in the previously mentioned link.
- I have added the N2 too, thinking that the single component wrapped/"stucked" into one group can be the cause; and then I changed the sellar problems structure I still can access derivatives in the sellar problem but not in mine.

I am not sure what more insight I can give. There can be an obvious thing i am missing. 
Any idea?

Here is the N^2 diagrams of my problem and the sample problem.

[image]

[image]

Here is the code snippet.

```
prob = Problem()
probname = prob.model = Group()
recordername='recorder.sql'
GLOBAL_DESIGN_VAR = IndepVarComp()
#"The design variables Indepvar - Promotes none of the variables"
probname.add_subsystem('GLOBAL_DESIGN_VAR', GLOBAL_DESIGN_VAR)

listofloadcases=[inp.fatiguename]
AERO_GroupName='AERO%s' %''.join(listofloadcases)
probname.add_subsystem(AERO_GroupName, AERO(loadcase=listofloadcases))       

for key,val in infodict['sysdes']['desvar'].items():
    GLOBAL_DESIGN_VAR.add_output(key, val['init'])   
    probname.add_design_var('GLOBAL_DESIGN_VAR.{}'.format(key),lower=val['min'], upper=val['max'])     
    probname.connect('GLOBAL_DESIGN_VAR.{}'.format(key), '{}.{}'.format(AERO_GroupName,key))
probname.add_objective('{}.cumPSDerror'.format(AERO_GroupName))
probname.add_constraint('{}.cumDELerror'.format(AERO_GroupName),upper=0.1)

prob.driver=ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
prob.driver.options['disp'] = True
prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1e-9

recorder = SqliteRecorder(recordername)
prob.driver.add_recorder(recorder)
prob.driver.recording_options['includes'] = []
prob.driver.recording_options['record_inputs'] = True
#        prob.driver.recording_options['record_outputs'] = True
prob.driver.recording_options['record_objectives'] = True
prob.driver.recording_options['record_constraints'] = True
prob.driver.recording_options['record_desvars'] = True
prob.driver.recording_options['record_derivatives'] = True

prob.setup(check=True)

prob.run_driver()

prob.cleanup()

cr = CaseReader('recorder.sql')

# Get derivatives associated with the last iteration.
derivs = cr.get_case(0).jacobian

# check that derivatives have been recorded.
print(set(derivs.keys()))
```

this is what I get when i run this

```
case = cr.get_case(-1)
print(case)
print(case.jacobian.keys())
```

so print(case) works but jacobian is empty

```
driver rank0:SLSQP|20 {'GLOBAL_DESIGN_VAR.d2100': array([1.29472574]), 'GLOBAL_DESIGN_VAR.Factor_c': array([1.29491178]), 'GLOBAL_DESIGN_VAR.lus': array([1.28847898]), 
'GLOBAL_DESIGN_VAR.ng': array([1.29981202]), 'GLOBAL_DESIGN_VAR.bl': array([1.2948257]), 'GLOBAL_DESIGN_VAR.d1700': array([1.29472449]),
 'GLOBAL_DESIGN_VAR.sFactor_c': array([1.29981202]), 'GoldflexFLS12.error': array([3.04801276]), 'GoldflexFLS12.Lerror': array([0.73301603])}

 Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-9a0bfa8ec35f>", line 5, in <module>
    print(case.jacobian.keys())

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

NEW CODE that one can run;

```
from openmdao.api import Problem, ScipyOptimizeDriver, ExecComp, IndepVarComp, SqliteRecorder, CaseReader
from openmdao.api import Group
from openmdao.api import ExplicitComponent

class Exp(ExplicitComponent):    

    def setup(self):          
        self.add_input('des1',val=1)  
        self.add_input('des2',val=1)  
        self.add_output('out',val=1)                                          
        self.add_output('con',val=1)                                          
        self.declare_partials('*', '*',method='fd',step=0.001)

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        outputs['out']=inputs['des1']**2+inputs['des2']
        outputs['con']=inputs['des1']

class AERO(Group):
    def setup(self):        
        self.add_subsystem('Exp',Exp(),promotes=['*'])


infodict={'desvar':{'des1':{"fdstep": 0.1,"init": 1.0,"max": 1.3,"min": 0.8},'des2':{"fdstep": 0.1,"init": 2.0,"max": 1.3,"min": 0.8}}}

prob = Problem()
probname = prob.model = Group()
recordername='recorder.sql'
GLOBAL_DESIGN_VAR = IndepVarComp()
probname.add_subsystem('GLOBAL_DESIGN_VAR', GLOBAL_DESIGN_VAR,promotes=['*'])
probname.add_subsystem('AERO', AERO(),promotes=['*']) 
for key,val in infodict['desvar'].items():
    GLOBAL_DESIGN_VAR.add_output(key, val['init'])   
    probname.add_design_var(key,lower=val['min'], upper=val['max'])     
probname.add_objective('out')
probname.add_constraint('con',upper=0.1)

prob.driver=ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
prob.driver.options['disp'] = True
prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1e-9

recorder = SqliteRecorder(recordername)
prob.driver.add_recorder(recorder)
prob.driver.recording_options['includes'] = []
prob.driver.recording_options['record_inputs'] = True
#        prob.driver.recording_options['record_outputs'] = True
prob.driver.recording_options['record_objectives'] = True
prob.driver.recording_options['record_constraints'] = True
prob.driver.recording_options['record_desvars'] = True
prob.driver.recording_options['record_derivatives'] = True

prob.setup(check=True)

prob.run_driver()

prob.cleanup()

cr = CaseReader(recordername)

# Get derivatives associated with the last iteration.
derivs = cr.get_case(0).jacobian

# check that derivatives have been recorded.
print(set(derivs.keys()))
```

Comment: We really need some sample code to work with here. I don't see any `list_inputs` calls in the link provided. 

My guess is that you're attaching the recorder to a system, probably the top level system, and then calling `run_model`.  if you have a NonlinearBlockGaussSeidel Solver, which doesn't need derivatives, then non would be recorded and you won't be able to access them.

Comment: @JustinGray It is a single component problem as the N2 above shows apart from the IndepVarComp. And it is the default solver LinearRunOnce (i am assuming). I am attaching the recorder to the problem.driver.add_recorder(etc) so I thouhgt this should give the total derivatives per iteration. Am I mistakend?

Comment: @JustinGray I added a new code that can be run by you at the end of the question.  I hope you get a notification for this comment. The only difference i see is the explicit component being inside the 'group' must be causing the problem. but could you explain why and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the default driver (RunOnceDriver) and calling run_driver(), then the reason you don't see any derivatives is that the default driver never asks for them, so they are never computed.

So you need to pick a gradient based driver, and then you also need to be sure to set

`prob.driver.recording_options['record_derivatives'] = True`

Here is a minimum working example:

```
from openmdao.api import Problem, ScipyOptimizeDriver, ExecComp, IndepVarComp, SqliteRecorder, CaseReader

# build the model 
prob = Problem() 
indeps = prob.model.add_subsystem('indeps', IndepVarComp()) 
indeps.add_output('x', 3.0) 
indeps.add_output('y', -4.0) 

prob.model.add_subsystem('paraboloid', ExecComp('f = (x-3)**2 + x*y + (y+4)**2 - 3')) 

prob.model.connect('indeps.x', 'paraboloid.x') 
prob.model.connect('indeps.y', 'paraboloid.y') 

prob.driver = ScipyOptimizeDriver() 
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP' 

recorder = SqliteRecorder("cases.sql")
prob.driver.add_recorder(recorder)
prob.driver.recording_options['record_derivatives'] = True


prob.model.add_design_var('indeps.x', lower=-50, upper=50) 
prob.model.add_design_var('indeps.y', lower=-50, upper=50) 
prob.model.add_objective('paraboloid.f') 

prob.setup() 
prob.run_driver() 


# minimum value 
print(prob['paraboloid.f']) 
# location of the minimum 
print(prob['indeps.x']) 
print(prob['indeps.y'])

prob.cleanup()

cr = CaseReader("cases.sql")

# driver_cases = cr.list_cases('driver')

# Get derivatives associated with the last iteration.
case = cr.get_case(-1)
print(case)

# check that derivatives have been recorded.
print(case.jacobian.keys())
```

Comment: I might have mislead you with the "LinearRunOnce driver" wording. 
I guess I meant LinearRunOnce solver. As it is stated in the manual this
is the default and I do not change it. But the driver is ScipyOptimizer with SLSQ. I thought there is still a
linear system to be solved for the total derivatives. Please see the updated question with the minimal
code I still can not get derivatives output.

Comment: first, if you run the provided file I gave in my answer, does it giver derivatives for you? I see them on my machine, so if not... you probably just don't have an up to date openmdao. We recently released V2.6. Try updating to that. Second, the example you gave doesn't run through. It needs import and relies on some variable that is not defined : `listofloadcases=[inp.fatiguename]`

Comment: I get the derivatives both from your example and the example in the manual. But somehow I can not access in my code example. And yes the code snippet I pasted to my question is not runnable as the group added to the problem contains an explicit component that calls an "external python code" that is confidential. I put the code there to check if i was making an obvious mistake in the way i add the model and recorder etc. My question has the N2 diagram of this problem too. I can not distinguish any difference between the way i add recorder to the problem in comparison to yours.

Comment: But when I run the last part i added what I get to the end of my question

Comment: I can not provide any more guidance without an example that I can test out. If you can modify your example with a toy component instead of the external one, then I can take another look