# i can not manage to record/access derivatives 2

Tags: openmdao

As a continuation of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54801157/i-can-not-manage-to-record-access-derivatives) I added a dummy code with which I have trouble accessing derivatives. 
I also added comp variable. This is just a flag to convert the problem 
with a explicit component or a group that containing the explicit component.

```
from openmdao.api import Problem, ScipyOptimizeDriver, ExecComp, IndepVarComp, SqliteRecorder, CaseReader
from openmdao.api import Group
from openmdao.api import ExplicitComponent
comp=True
class Exp(ExplicitComponent):    

    def setup(self):          
        self.add_input('des1',val=1)  
        self.add_input('des2',val=1)  
        self.add_output('out',val=1)                                          
        self.add_output('con',val=1)                                          
        self.declare_partials('*', '*',method='fd',step=0.001)

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        outputs['out']=inputs['des1']**2+inputs['des2']
        outputs['con']=inputs['des1']

class AERO(Group):
    def setup(self):        
        self.add_subsystem('Exp',Exp(),promotes=['*'])


infodict={'desvar':{'des1':{"fdstep": 0.1,"init": 1.0,"max": 1.3,"min": 0.8},
                    'des2':{"fdstep": 0.1,"init": 2.0,"max": 1.3,"min": 0.8}}}

prob = Problem()
probname = prob.model = Group()
recordername='recorder1.sql'
GLOBAL_DESIGN_VAR = IndepVarComp()
probname.add_subsystem('GLOBAL_DESIGN_VAR', GLOBAL_DESIGN_VAR,promotes=['*'])

if comp:
    probname.add_subsystem('Exp', Exp(),promotes=['*']) 
else:
    probname.add_subsystem('AERO', AERO(),promotes=['*']) 


for key,val in infodict['desvar'].items():
    GLOBAL_DESIGN_VAR.add_output(key, val['init'])   
    probname.add_design_var(key,lower=val['min'], upper=val['max'])   

probname.add_objective('out')
probname.add_constraint('con',upper=0.1)

prob.driver=ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
prob.driver.options['disp'] = True
prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1e-9

recorder = SqliteRecorder(recordername)
prob.driver.add_recorder(recorder)
#prob.driver.recording_options['includes'] = []
#prob.driver.recording_options['record_inputs'] = True
#        prob.driver.recording_options['record_outputs'] = True
#prob.driver.recording_options['record_objectives'] = True
#prob.driver.recording_options['record_constraints'] = True
#prob.driver.recording_options['record_desvars'] = True
prob.driver.recording_options['record_derivatives'] = True

prob.setup(check=True)

prob.run_driver()

prob.cleanup()

cr = CaseReader(recordername)

# driver_cases = cr.list_cases('driver')

# Get derivatives associated with the last iteration.
case = cr.get_case(-1)
print(case)

# check that derivatives have been recorded.
print(case.jacobian.keys())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up your script a bit, but other than having a bad initial condition on `des2` (2.0 was outside your given bounds) the optimization ran fine. With the bad initial guess, it hit maxiter and gave a `NAN`. Either way though, derivatives were recorded.

```
from openmdao.api import Problem, ScipyOptimizeDriver, ExecComp, IndepVarComp, SqliteRecorder, CaseReader
from openmdao.api import Group
from openmdao.api import ExplicitComponent

class Exp(ExplicitComponent):    

    def setup(self):          
        self.add_input('des1',val=1)  
        self.add_input('des2',val=1)  
        self.add_output('out',val=1)                                          
        self.add_output('con',val=1)                                          
        self.declare_partials('*', '*',method='fd',step=0.001)

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        outputs['out']=inputs['des1']**2+inputs['des2']
        outputs['con']=inputs['des1']


prob = Problem()

dvs = IndepVarComp()
prob.model.add_subsystem('dvs', dvs, promotes=['*'])

prob.model.add_subsystem('Exp', Exp(),promotes=['*']) 

dvs.add_output('des1', 1.0)   
prob.model.add_design_var('des1',lower=0.8, upper=1.3)   

# dvs.add_output('des2', 2.0) # BAD INITIAL GUESS!!!!!  
dvs.add_output('des2', 1.0)   
prob.model.add_design_var('des2',lower=0.8, upper=1.3)   

prob.model.add_objective('out')
prob.model.add_constraint('con',upper=0.1)

prob.driver=ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
prob.driver.options['disp'] = True
prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1e-9


RECORDER_NAME = 'recorder1.sql'
recorder = SqliteRecorder(RECORDER_NAME)

prob.driver.add_recorder(recorder)

#prob.driver.recording_options['includes'] = []
#prob.driver.recording_options['record_inputs'] = True
#        prob.driver.recording_options['record_outputs'] = True
#prob.driver.recording_options['record_objectives'] = True
#prob.driver.recording_options['record_constraints'] = True
#prob.driver.recording_options['record_desvars'] = True

prob.driver.recording_options['record_derivatives'] = True

prob.setup(check=True)

prob.run_driver()

prob.cleanup()

cr = CaseReader(RECORDER_NAME)

cases = cr.get_cases()
for c in cases: 
    print(c.outputs['des1'], c.outputs['des2'])
    if c.jacobian is not None: 
        print(c.jacobian)
    print()
```

When run this gives:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: 1.4400000000000002
            Iterations: 7
            Function evaluations: 3
            Gradient evaluations: 3
Optimization Complete
-----------------------------------
[1.] [1.]

[1.] [1.]

[0.8] [0.8]
{('out', 'des1'): array([[2.001]]), ('out', 'des2'): array([[1.]]), ('con', 'des1'): array([[1.]]), ('con', 'des2'): array([[-0.]])}

[0.8] [0.8]
{('out', 'des1'): array([[1.601]]), ('out', 'des2'): array([[1.]]), ('con', 'des1'): array([[1.]]), ('con', 'des2'): array([[-0.]])}
```

Notice that not every case has derivatives associated with it. Line search steps are taken without recomputing derivatives, so none are recorded. In your original test script, the last case had no derivatives, but some of the preceding cases did (all will filled with `NAN` though).

Comment: the code in the question was with random calculations so i did not pay attention for the initial value being out of bounds. but i think i have been always looking at the first or the last iteration where there was no gradient due to line search, i guess thanks....